# on giving inputs to my temperature,Humidity,Number of people fields, i want my speed n Temperature fields to be get coloured

Tags: javascript, php

On giving inputs to my temperature,Humidity,Number of people fields, i want my speed n Temperature fields to be automatically get coloured. Like when i give input as temperature=1,Humidity=1,Number Of people=1, on click on sumbit button i want Speed n Temperature field -1st box should be get coloured. Similarly on giving different inputs,i want my speed n temperature box should get coloured. how should i do dat???? Any kind of help will useful!!

```html
<html>
<frameset rows="50%,50%">
   <frame name="top" src="k7.php"/>
   <frame name="bottom" src="n3.html"/>
   </frameset>
</html>
```

This is my k7.php code

```html
<?php
    session_start();

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if( !empty( $_POST['bttn'] ) && !empty( $_POST['type'] ) ){

            $type=$_POST['type'];
            $bttn=$_POST['bttn'];


            $_SESSION['buttonClicked'][ $type ]=$bttn;

            exit( json_encode( $_SESSION['buttonClicked'] ) );
        }
    }
?>
 
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Set Colours of Buttons</title>
        <style>
        .green{
            background-color: green;
            border: 1px solid black;
            color: white;
            padding: 8px 30px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
        }
        .blue{
            background-color: blue;
            border: 1px solid black;
            color: white;
            padding: 8px 30px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
        }
        .yellow{
            background-color: yellow;
            border: 1px solid black;
            color: black;
            padding: 8px 30px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
        }
        .red{
            background-color: red;
            border: 1px solid black;
            color: white;
            padding: 8px 30px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
        }
        input[type='button']{
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 8px 30px;
            margin:0 0.25rem;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
        }
        </style>
        <script>
            (function(){
                var colours={
                    1:'red',
                    2:'blue',
                    3:'green',
                    4:'yellow'
                };
                var flags={ 
                    passive:true,
                    capture:false
                };
                function setcolours(e){
                    var _class=this.dataset.class;
                    var col=this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"][data-class="'+_class+'"]');

                    /* Clear previous colour classes assigned */
                    col.forEach(function(e,i,a){
                        Object.values( colours ).forEach(function( c ){
                            e.classList.remove( c );
                        });
                    });

                    /* Add colour class to any element with a value equal to or less that selected button value */
                    for( var i=this.value; i > 0; i-- ){
                        try{
                            if( col[ i - 1 ].nodeType==1 )col[ i - 1 ].classList.add( colours[ col[ i - 1 ].value ] )
                        }catch( err ){
                            console.info( err );
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    ajax( this.value, this.dataset.type );
                }
                function ajax( value, type ){
                    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 ){
                            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML=this.response;
                        }
                    };
                    var params='bttn='+value+'&type='+type;
                    xhr.open( 'post', location.href, true );
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    xhr.send( params );
                }
                function bindEvents(e){
                    var col = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]');
                    if( col && col.length > 0 ){
                        for( var n in col ){
                            if( col[ n ].nodeType==1 ){
                                col[ n ].addEventListener( 'click', setcolours.bind( col[ n ] ), flags );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents, flags );
            }());
        </script>
  
    </head>
    <body>

        
  
            <div align="left">Temperature </div>

            <input type="button" class="button" data-class='b' data-type='temperature' value="1">
            <input type="button" class="button" data-class='b' data-type='temperature' value="2">
            <input type="button" class="button" data-class='b' data-type='temperature' value="3">
            <input type="button" class="button" data-class='b' data-type='temperature' value="4">
            <br />
            <br />
            <div align="left">Humidity</div>
            <input type="button" class="button1" data-class='b1' data-type='humidity' value="1">
            <input type="button" class="button1" data-class='b1' data-type='humidity' value="2">
            <input type="button" class="button1" data-class='b1' data-type='humidity' value="3">
            <input type="button" class="button1" data-class='b1' data-type='humidity' value="4">
            <br />
            <br />
            <div align="left">Number of people </div>
            <input type="button" class="button2" data-class='b2' data-type='people' value="1">
            <input type="button" class="button2" data-class='b2' data-type='people' value="2">
            <input type="button" class="button2" data-class='b2' data-type='people' value="3">
            <input type="button" class="button2" data-class='b2' data-type='people' value="4">
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type='submit' value='submit'>
             
    
          </form>


        

        <pre id='results'></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my n3.html code

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.box1 {
    
    width: 100px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    background-color:white;
    border: 1px solid black;
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div align="left">Speed: </div>
 <div align="right" class="box1"></div>
 <div align="right" class="box1"></div>
 <div align="right" class="box1"></div>
 <div align="right" class="box1"></div>
 <div align="right" class="box1"></div>
 <br><br>
 <br>
 <div align="left">Temperature: </div>
 <div align="right" class="box1"></div>
 <div align="right" class="box1"></div>
 <div align="right" class="box1"></div>
 <div align="right" class="box1"></div>
 <div align="right" class="box1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tag-spamming a question with tags unrelated to your question is never a good idea. Remove the `java` and `jsp` tags as there is none of that in your question. Doesn't look to be related to `jquery` either.

Comment: Please describe all possibilities. For e.g. if temperature=1,Humidity=1,Number Of people=1 then Speed n Temperature field -1st box get colored....................

Comment: @Jaydeep Mor. Some of my possibilities are    1)Temperature=1 Humidity=2  people=2  then  Speed=1,2box should be coloured      Temperature=1,2,3 box should be coloured
2)Temperature=1 Humidity=2  people=4 then   Speed=1,2,3,4 Temperature=1,2,3 boxes get coloured
3)Temperature=1 Humidity=3  people=2   then Speed=1,2,3,4,5  Temperature=1,2,3 boxes get coloured
4)Temperature=2 Humidity=2  people=3  then Speed=1,2,3,4      Temperature=1,2,3 boxes get coloured
5)Temperature=3 Humidity=4  people=3  then Speed=1,2,3,4,5  Temperature=1,2,3,4 boxes get coloured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the following can be adapted to your frameset layout somehow - it uses a new function but is otherwise the same code as previous answer ( more or less anyway )

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $svar='buttonClicked';

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if( !empty( $_POST['bttn'] ) && !empty( $_POST['type'] ) ){

            $type=$_POST['type'];
            $bttn=$_POST['bttn'];


            $_SESSION[ $svar ][ $type ]=$bttn;

            header( 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK', true, 200 );
            header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
            exit( json_encode( $_SESSION[ $svar ] ) );
        }
    }

    if( !empty( $_GET['reset'] ) && $_GET['reset']=='true' && isset( $_SESSION[ $svar ] ) ){
        unset( $_SESSION[ $svar ] );
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] );
    }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Set Colours of Buttons</title>
        <style>
            body, body *{
                font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;
                font-size:1rem;
                color:black;
            }
            input[type='button']{
                background-color:white;
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
                margin:0 0.25rem;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: inline-block;
                cursor: pointer;
                float: left;
            }
            .green{
                background-color: green!important;
            }
            .blue{
                background-color: blue!important;
            }
            .yellow{
                background-color: yellow!important;
            }
            .red{
                background-color: red!important;
            }
            .pink{
                background-color: pink!important;
            }
            .orange{
                background-color: orange!important;
            }
            .purple{
                background-color: purple!important;
            }
            .brown{
                background-color: brown!important;
            }
            legend,fieldset{
                border:none;
            }
            legend{
                border-bottom:1px solid gray;
                border-left:3px solid black;
                padding:0.5rem;
                margin:0 0 0 0.25rem;
            }
            fieldset.boxes > div{
                width: 4.5rem;
                height: 2rem;
                margin: 0 0.25rem;
                padding: 0;
                float: left;
                background-color:white;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            (function(){
                var obj={};
                var colours={
                    1:'red',
                    2:'orange',
                    3:'yellow',
                    4:'pink',
                    5:'brown',
                    6:'purple',
                    7:'blue',
                    8:'green'
                };
                var flags={ 
                    passive:true,
                    capture:false
                };
                function setcolours(e){
                    var col=this.parentNode.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="button"]' );
                    obj[ this.parentNode.dataset.type ]=this.value;

                    /* Clear previous colour classes assigned */
                    col.forEach(function(e,i,a){
                        Object.values( colours ).forEach(function( c ){
                            e.classList.remove( c );
                        });
                    });

                    /* Add colour class to any element with a value equal to or less that selected button value */
                    for( var i=this.value; i > 0; i-- ){
                        try{
                            if( col[ i - 1 ].nodeType==1 )col[ i - 1 ].classList.add( colours[ col[ i - 1 ].value ] )
                        }catch( err ){
                            console.info( err );
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    /* set the colour of div boxes */
                    setboxes.call( this, e, obj );


                    /* send the ajax request to store values into session variables &/or whatever actions are required */
                    ajax( this.value, this.parentNode.dataset.type );
                }


                /* new function to set colour of boxes if all buttons clicked have same value */
                function setboxes( event, _obj ){
                    /* get references from global obj */
                    var keys=Object.keys( _obj );
                    var values=Object.values( _obj );


                    if( keys.length==3 ){
                        /* Are all items of the same value? */
                        var value=values.reduce( function(a,b){ return a==b ? a : false } );

                        /* get nodelist of boxes */
                        var col=document.querySelectorAll('fieldset.boxes div');

                        /* If the values are all the same - set colour */
                        if( value ){
                            /* clear previous colour - if any */
                            col.forEach(function(e,i,a){
                                Object.values( colours ).forEach(function( c ){
                                    e.classList.remove( c );
                                });
                            });
                            /* assign new colour */
                            for( var i=value; i > 0; i-- ){
                                try{
                                    col.forEach(function(item,index,array){
                                        if( item.dataset.value <= value )item.classList.add( colours[ value ] );
                                    });
                                }catch( err ){
                                    console.info( err )
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }

                        } else {
                            /* mismatch in values - remove colours */
                            col.forEach(function(e,i,a){
                                Object.values( colours ).forEach(function( c ){
                                    e.classList.remove( c );
                                });
                            });
                            /* ???? */
                            values.forEach( function(value){
                                col.forEach( function(box){
                                    if( box.dataset.value <= value ) box.classList.add( colours[ box.dataset.value ] )
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }

                function ajax( value, type ){
                    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 ){
                            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML=this.response;
                        }
                    };
                    var params='bttn='+value+'&type='+type;
                    xhr.open( 'post', location.href, true );
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    xhr.send( params );
                }
                function reset(e){
                    location.search='reset=true';
                }
                function bindEvents(e){
                    var col = document.querySelectorAll('form > fieldset > input[type="button"]');
                    if( col && col.length > 0 ){
                        for( var n in col ){
                            if( col[ n ].nodeType==1 ){
                                col[ n ].addEventListener( 'click', setcolours.bind( col[ n ] ), flags );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    var bttn = document.querySelectorAll('form > input[ type="reset" ]')[0];
                        bttn.onclick=reset;
                }
                document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents, flags );
            }());
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action='chk.php' method='post'>

            <fieldset data-type='temperature'>
                <legend>Temperature</legend>
                <input type="button" value="1" />
                <input type="button" value="2" />
                <input type="button" value="3" />
                <input type="button" value="4" />
                <input type="button" value="5" />
                <input type="button" value="6" />
                <input type="button" value="7" />
                <input type="button" value="8" />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset data-type='humidity'>
                <legend>Humidity</legend>
                <input type="button" value="1" />
                <input type="button" value="2" />
                <input type="button" value="3" />
                <input type="button" value="4" />
                <input type="button" value="5" />
                <input type="button" value="6" />
                <input type="button" value="7" />
                <input type="button" value="8" />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset data-type='people'>
                <legend>Number of people</legend>
                <input type="button" value="1" />
                <input type="button" value="2" />
                <input type="button" value="3" />
                <input type="button" value="4" />
                <input type="button" value="5" />
                <input type="button" value="6" />
                <input type="button" value="7" />
                <input type="button" value="8" />
            </fieldset>

            <br />
            <br />

            <fieldset class='boxes' data-type='box-speed'>
                <legend>Speed</legend>
                <div data-value=1></div>
                <div data-value=2></div>
                <div data-value=3></div>
                <div data-value=4></div>
                <div data-value=5></div>
                <div data-value=6></div>
                <div data-value=7></div>
                <div data-value=8></div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class='boxes' data-type='box-temperature'>
                <legend>Temperature</legend>
                <div data-value=1></div>
                <div data-value=2></div>
                <div data-value=3></div>
                <div data-value=4></div>
                <div data-value=5></div>
                <div data-value=6></div>
                <div data-value=7></div>
                <div data-value=8></div>
            </fieldset>

            <input type='submit' value='submit'>
            <input type='reset' value='reset'>
        </form>

        <pre id='results'></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wat can i do ,if i want   to set colour of boxes if all buttons clicked have different values.

Comment: @RamRaider.wat can i do ,if i want   to set colour of boxes if all buttons clicked have different values.   like Temperature =1, humidity=2 Number of people=4,i want speed =1st,2nd,3rd boxes get coloured and Temperature=1st,2nd,3rd,4th boxes get coloured.      Similarly i have many different possibilites of differnt values. how can i do??

Comment: .your code is  correct.But for specific input like   Temperatue=1,Humidity=2,Number of People=4,i want in speed field only 1st,2nd n 3rd box should get coloured. But i m not getting that!!!!!!! As i m new to coding. Can u expalin ur code by writting comments in d code!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a go at working out the logic. You need to be explicit with the requirements and by now you should have an idea how to do this based upon all the code given thus far. Also, the code is commented

Comment: what rules does the colouing follow? Please define the rules

Comment: @RamRaider.There is no specific rules for colouring.All the parameters which i am considering in webpage is about Air Conditioner.For some specific inputs, i dont want my Speed and Temperature to be return same output.
Like when my Temperature=1,Humidity=1,People=2 i want my Temperature=1st,2nd box to be coloured and for Speed,only 1st box to be get coloured.Similarly some of requirements are as follows:

1)Temperature=1 Humidity=1  people=3  then  Speed=1,2        Temperature=1,2 boxes get coloured
2)Temperature=1 Humidity=2  people=2   then Speed=1,2      Temperature=1,2,3 get coloured

Comment: @RamRaider.4)Temperature=1 Humidity=3  people=2   then Speed=1,2,3,4,5  Temperature=1,2,3 boxes get coloured
5)Temperature=2 Humidity=2  people=3  then Speed=1,2,3,4    Temperature=1,2,3
6)Temperature=3 Humidity=4  people=3  then Speed=1,2,3,4,5  Temperature=1,2,3,4
7)Temperature=4 Humidity=1  people=4  then Speed=1,2,3,4,5   Temperature=1,2,3,4
8)Temperature=4 Humidity=3  people=4  then Speed=1,2,3,4,5 Temperature=1,2,3,4,5